# Turning a list of lists into a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, graph, tuples

Hi there I am having a small problem with a code I am trying to implement.
I wish to convert a list of lists into a dictionary where the keys refer to the lists position in the original list of lists, and the values are a list of the items that were in said list (from the original list of lists). I also wish to remove all of the Nones present in the original list of lists. For example:

```
[[(1, None), (2, None)], [(0, None), (2, None)], [(1, None), (0, None)]]
```

I would want this to become:

```
{0: [1, 2], 1: [0, 2], 2: [1, 0]}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a basic dict and list comprehension

```
raw = [[(1, None), (2, None)], [(0, None), (2, None)], [(1, None), (0, None)]]
print {i: [el[0] for el in l] for i, l in enumerate(raw)}
```

prints

```
{0: [1, 2], 1: [0, 2], 2: [1, 0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, if you wanted to use `lambda` and `map`:

```
dict(map(lambda i: (li.index(i), [i[0][0], i[1][0]]), li))
```

An alternative dictionary comprehension which uses the `index` method instead of `enumerate`:

```
{li.index(i):[el[0] for el in i] for i in li}
```

Comment: just a side note - dict comprehension proposed has quadratic complexity as index is linear and we call it linearly many times.