# How can I convert a list of lists into a dictionary of lists in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have a list with four lists in it. I want to assign each inner list a name, basically convert the list with four lists into a dictionary with four named lists. How can I do that in a Pythonic way? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323121/turning-a-list-of-lists-into-a-dictionary-of-lists) question but it was too specfic.

```
dictionary["list1"] = lists[0]
dictionary["list2"] = lists[1]
dictionary["list3"] = lists[2]
dictionary["list4"] = lists[3]
```

Edit: I would like to know how to do that with arbitrary dictionary keys - not just list1,list2,list3, etc.

Comment: Have you tried to adapt that answer to work for you? Your problem is quite similar to that one

Comment: It was too dense for me to understand, and I thought generalizing the problem a bit would get me a simple answer.

Comment: Then you are not going to understand the solution I posted. You might want to post something that you've attempted, so that we can show you where you went wrong

Comment: Why the negativity? I understood it in a few minutes :)

Comment: My solution is no more complex than the solution on the post you linked. I wasn't being negative - simply stating that you have two approximately equally complex solutions to two very similar problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
import itertools

names = "mains_voltage mains_time CT_voltage CT_time".split()
answer = {name:L for name,L in itertools.izip(names, lists)}
```

Comment: I would like to know how to do that with arbitrary dictionary keys - not just list1,list2,list3, etc

Comment: what would be a names source? please clarify.

Comment: The dictionary will be initialized with keys, but empty values

Comment: @Rogalski: `names source`? What do you mean?

Comment: @M.Hassaan: it will have empty values only if `lists` contains empty lists

Comment: I want to know how we can do it regardless of the names source. However, the names of the lists should be the following: "mains_voltage, mains_time, CT_voltage, CT_time"